# Вставить мультипэйдж в мультипэйдж

Tags: access

Почему в access нельзя вставить мультипэйдж в мультипэйдж?
Как выйти из ситуации? Мне нужна именно такая навигация...

**Обновление**

Не хотел пользоваться языком VBA в access, а хотел воспользоваться стандартными возможностями программы. Ситуация такая. Есть форма. На форму добавляю стандартную мультипэйдж со множеством вкладок. На каждую вкладку этого мультипэйджа хотел добавить по мультипэйджу. В итоге должно было получится так, что открываешь одну вкладку, а там еще множество вкладок. Но никак не получается вставить одну внутрь другой. Они добавляются одна поверх другой. Почему и что делать?

Comment: @Владимир_C, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Упростить интерфейс - в такой сложной структуре мало кто будет разбираться. Сделайте, например, навигацию как в окне опций современных офисных приложений.